# Heroku pg:psql not working - PATH not correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql, heroku

I want to connect to the heroku pg:psql but it's not working anymore. Don't know what to do after searching the web and also Stackoverflow for hours.
The command `heroku pg:psql` gives me this error:

```
The local psql command could not be located
```

`For help installing psql, see` [article about local-postgres](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-postgresql)

Working on a Mac with OS X (Version 10.9.1), Ruby 1.9.3. and Rails 4.0.1.

My `database.yml` is as following:

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: outspotly_v1_development
pool: 5
username: fabianwydler
host: localhost
port: 5432

test:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: outspotly_v1_test
pool: 5
username: fabianwydler
host: localhost
port: 5432

production:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: outspotly_v1_production
pool: 5
username: fabianwydler
host: 
port:
```

Is there, perhaps, something wrong with my $PATH?

```
heroku run rails db
Running `rails db` attached to terminal... up, run.3540
Couldn't find database client: psql. Check your $PATH and try again.
Fabians-MacBook-Pro:outspotly_v1 fabianwydler$ echo $PATH
/Users/fabianwydler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/fabianwydler/.rvm/gems/ruby-              1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/fabianwydler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/fabianwydler/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

If the $PATH is wrong I don't know how to handle this because I'm not so familiar on Mac.

Thank you very much for your help.

Greetings, Fabian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a local copy of `psql`. By far the easiest way is to install [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and then postgresql:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
brew install postgresql`

Comment: I use the Postgres.app. Is it in this case also needed to install the local copy with homebrew?

Comment: I use Postgress.app as well. But installing homebrew's postgresql is the easiest way to get the psql client binary that heroku toolbelt is looking for. You won't actually run the postgresql server.

Comment: install postgresql via brew does the job. Thank you very much @dankohn